# N choose K and assumptions.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-game-theory, multisets

I have a process by which people must compare a bunch of items against each other in pairs. For now, let's say we're comparing two at a time from a set of six items. The problem is that people end up having to make 15 comparisons to compare everything (n choose k), which is tedious. However, let's say that "assuming" one degree of accuracy is okay. That is, we can say that because A > B and B > C, that A > C, and because B > C, and C > D, that B > D, and so on. Is this the only (and best?) way to use assumptions for this combination? Does anyone have an idea about how to compare things like this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the range of items and how pairs are compared.  Each item might correspond to two characteristics, so we can represent it as an ordered pair.  If the two values for the two items are just added, you can collapse the two characteristics to the sum and you get the transitive ranking you are hoping for.  If you multiply the corresponding values of the pair and add the products this will not work.  Maybe A is $(10,1)$, B is $(1,10)$ and C is $(4,3)$.  Just adding the two values would lead you to choose A,B, but that is the worst you can do as it only scores $20$ while B,C scores $34$ and A,C scores $43$.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but I'm not sure how you're getting those numbers. So, you're saying that if I have a range of items -- a selection of cats, for example -- and cats have two qualities -- for example, cuteness and stupidity, that I can use those values to reduce the number of comparisons? Here are four cats:

Abby (C: 10, S: 1),
Boots (C: 1, S: 10),
Clown (C: 5, S: 6), and
Dumbo (C: 3, S: 7).

How could I use your method to reduce the number of comparisons it would require to get the order of these elements, via n choose k? Normally I have to make 6 comparisons, right?

Comment: I just made up the numbers to show how the method of scoring pairs might make it hard to rank the individual items.  I claim that depending on the scoring method there may not be a linear ranking-the value of one cat will depend on the characteristics of the other cats it can be paired with.  In that case the number of comparisons is one less than the number of sets to find the maximum, so picking a pair out of four takes five comparisons.